# How do I make my textured plane into a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I want to make a tunnel with a texture on inner walls.

How can I make my plane into a cylinder?

Comment: I guess your tunnel is cylinder, so what you need to do is to unwrap it, maybe the best way to do it is with the Follow Active Quad option, so that it will be displayed as a square UVmap, maybe look for some tutorials on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Why so? Instead,  make a NURBS/bezier semicircle and extrude it, setting the desired value in the Geometry section. Convert it to mesh, solidify **outside** and texturize the wall inside.To do that give it a different material color.

or simpler yet

Add a circle mesh, remove half of its vertices and extrude. Then do as above.